# Find a range in associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, range

I'm trying to find a range from associative arrays.
The data is from a Racelogic (car performance GPS box), so I specifically want to extract 0-100 from the arrays.

Full array can be found here: [link](http://www.vindfrisk.se/stackoverflow/test3.php)

Looks like this (sats,time,lat,long,velocity,heading,height,vert-vel,yaw-calc,slip,YAW__,YAW_,):

```
Array
(
[31] => Array
    (
        [0] => 006
        [1] => 194300,70
        [2] => +03560,94626
        [3] => -01079,53898
        [4] => 009,490
        [5] => 000,00
        [6] => +00048,59
        [7] => -000,432
        [8] => +000,0
        [9] => +0,00000E+00
        [10] => +0,00000E+00
        [11] => +0,00000E+00
        [12] => 
    )

[32] => Array
    (
        [0] => 005
        [1] => 194300,80
        [2] => +03560,94660
        [3] => -01079,53760
        [4] => 008,630
        [5] => 259,90
        [6] => +00050,46
        [7] => -000,180
        [8] => +000,0
        [9] => +0,00000E+00
        [10] => +0,00000E+00
        [11] => +0,00000E+00
        [12] => 
    )
)
```

And so on. In this case "4" is the velocity.
The data can contain many 0-100 runs and I would like to extract them. How I save the data doesn't matter, could be array or string.
The velocity value never hits "100,000" exactly so needs to be when it goes over, the range should however always start on "000,000".

I'm fairly decent in PHP but this logic/algorithm has got my head spinning know for a while. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry for being a bit unspecific, always clearer in your own head.
The arrays contain velocity data, and I want to extract acceleration runs, specifically 0-100. There are several 0-100 runs in the data at the moment. This means I don't only want min and max, I want all the data inbetween 0-100 for each run. My end goal is to save the range and play them back using D3.js, and compare between different cars.

Comment: "And so on. In this case "4" is the velocity. The data can contain many 0-100 runs and I would like to extract them". To clarify, do you want to extract the fourth column into its own array of values? I'm not sure from your question if you want to just pull these values out, or optionally filter them

Comment: So, for the example data, what would be the output you expect?

Comment: First run would be: array('000,000', '001,290', '001,610', '001,930'.......'099,110', '099,620', '100,130')

Second run: array('000,000', '000,820', '000,960', '001,600',........'099,510', '099,750', '100,230')

based on the data I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the clarification, I re-read your question and wrote something that should find all the "runs" inside the data.

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/NSNJ0L

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array('001', '194300,70', '+03560,94626', '-01079,53898', '109,490', '000,00', '+00048,59', '-000,432', '+000,0', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '', ),
    array('002', '194300,70', '+03560,94626', '-01079,53898', '209,490', '000,00', '+00048,59', '-000,432', '+000,0', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '', ),
    array('003', '194300,70', '+03560,94626', '-01079,53898', '009,490', '000,00', '+00048,59', '-000,432', '+000,0', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '', ),
    array('004', '194300,70', '+03560,94626', '-01079,53898', '039,490', '000,00', '+00048,59', '-000,432', '+000,0', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '', ),
    array('005', '194300,70', '+03560,94626', '-01079,53898', '069,490', '000,00', '+00048,59', '-000,432', '+000,0', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '', ),
    array('006', '194300,70', '+03560,94626', '-01079,53898', '099,490', '000,00', '+00048,59', '-000,432', '+000,0', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '', ),
    array('007', '194300,70', '+03560,94626', '-01079,53898', '109,490', '000,00', '+00048,59', '-000,432', '+000,0', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '', ),
    array('008', '194300,80', '+03560,94660', '-01079,53760', '128,630', '259,90', '+00050,46', '-000,180', '+000,0', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '', ),
    array('009', '194300,70', '+03560,94626', '-01079,53898', '001,490', '000,00', '+00048,59', '-000,432', '+000,0', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '', ),
    array('010', '194300,70', '+03560,94626', '-01079,53898', '051,490', '000,00', '+00048,59', '-000,432', '+000,0', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '', ),
    array('011', '194300,70', '+03560,94626', '-01079,53898', '101,490', '000,00', '+00048,59', '-000,432', '+000,0', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '', ),
    array('012', '194300,70', '+03560,94626', '-01079,53898', '019,490', '000,00', '+00048,59', '-000,432', '+000,0', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '+0,00000E+00', '', ),
);

    $targetColumn = 4;
    $minValue = 0;
    $maxValue = 100;

    $found = false;
    $filtered = array();
    $run = 0;

    foreach($data as $row){
        //get our target value
        $val = $row[$targetColumn];

        //parse it as a number
        $val = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $val));

        //if not found yet and our value is between the min and max, mark as found
        if(!$found && ($val >= $minValue && $val <= $maxValue)){
            $found = true;
        }

        //if found, add this value to the filtered array
        if($found){
            $filtered[$run][] = $row;

            //if our value is over the max, increment our run and reset found
            if($val > $maxValue){
                $run++;
                $found = false;
            }
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>'.print_r($filtered, true);
```

Comment: This solution doesn't start collecting data at "000,000", it starts at whatever number that is withing $minValue and $maxValue. I want the data to start at "000,000" and end at first value above "100,000". Also I want do be able to distinguish between different 0-100 runs.

Comment: Well that isn't very clear in your original question. In that case,  you would need to just loop over the array and likely toggle a boolean value to start adding into another array. I can write something really quick to show you.

Comment: I apologize for being unclear about what I wanted, I've updated the original question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is essentially what I asked for hence correct answer. Is it possible to get all 0-100 runs? As of now it break once it found the first 0-100.

Comment: updated it to get all the runs after I read your clarification. Essentially instead of "break" out of the loop, I increment a "run" number and reset $found so it will keep looking over later values and once the next one is "found" it will start adding to the filtered array under the next run number. The sample data I used is bad but enough to illustrate it working. I just copied the first row and modified the 5th value (index 4) to climb in value to above 100 and reset back down to ~0 + a little bit.

Comment: updated. Removed debug statement I left in there and added demo.

Comment: Hmm using this with the actual data don't work really as intended. The runs doesn't start with "000,000". http://www.vindfrisk.se/stackoverflow/screenshot.png Could you try with original data? found here http://www.vindfrisk.se/stackoverflow/bmw.csv 
I massage it like this.
    $csvData = file_get_contents(getcwd() . "/bmw.csv");
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$data = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $data[] = str_getcsv($line);
}

for ($x = 0; $x <= 30; $x++) {
    unset($data[$x]);
}

Comment: Did you want it to start when it first sees exactly `000,000`? I have it starting the first time it sees a value between 0 and 100. So if you have a run that goes from 0 to over 100 and then below 100, the next one will start right where that previous run went below 100. You can just change the first `if` in the loop to something like `if(!$found && $val == $minueVal){ ...etc`

Answer (score 2):

One very heavy way would be to sort the whole dataset by velocity:

```
$data_sorted = usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[4] < $b[4];
});
```

Another approach would be using `array_column` for extracting the velocities into an own array first:

```
$velocities = array_column($data, 4);
```

and then either use min() and max(), or sort() to get the minimal and maximal values.

And a 3rd attempt would be to just use a loop and 2 running variables.

```
$max = 0.0; $min = 100.0;
foreach ($data as $set) {
    $max = max($max, $set[4]);
    $min = min($min, $set[4]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, array_column() was quite neat, to make it easier to work with. However I dont want to sort anything. I want all data and the order they already are in when velocity first hits "000,000" all the way up to first value above "100,000".